# How to download artifact to local repository from 3-rd party repository and USE IT later?

Tags: maven

I would like to verify in my desktop that 3-rd party library will meet my needs.

I added dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oopsconsultancy</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmltask</artifactId>
  <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

My project does not compile:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project other-repo:other-repo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oopsconsultancy:xmltask:jar:1.16 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

That is OK, because xmltask is located in 3rd party repository. I downloaded them manually:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get         
-DrepoUrl=https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/
-Dartifact=com.oopsconsultancy:xmltask:1.16
```

Artifacts are downloaded to local repository:

> repositoryUrl parameter is deprecated. Use remoteRepositories instead
>
> Resolving com.oopsconsultancy:xmltask:jar:1.16 with transitive dependencies
>
> Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/com/oopsconsultancy/xmltask/1.16/xmltask-1.16.pom
>
> Downloaded: https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/com/oopsconsultancy/xmltask/1.16/xmltask-1.16.pom (569 B at 0.6 KB/sec)
>
> Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/com/oopsconsultancy/xmltask/1.16/xmltask-1.16.jar
>
> Downloaded: https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/com/oopsconsultancy/xmltask/1.16/xmltask-1.16.jar (75 KB at 99.0 KB/sec)

Unfortunately, `mvn compile` still does not work:

> Failed to execute goal on project other-repo: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project other-repo:other-repo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find com.oopsconsultancy:xmltask:jar:1.16 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I don't want configure 3-rd party remote repository in my project, because finally it will be hidden behind Artifactory.

What I want is download artifact to my local repository, check it works as I want and ask Artifactory boss include 3-rd party remote repository to mirror of central repo

## UPDATE

Content of downloaded xmltask-1.16.pom.lastUpdated

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Tue Nov 08 13:58:17 CET 2016
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1478609847661
https\://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/.lastUpdated=1478609897852
https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=
```

Comment: "I don't want configure 3-rd party remote repository in my project, because finally it will be hidden behind Artifactory." - these are the two choices you have. Create a <pluginRepository /> element, as long as the artifactory cannot mirror it.

Comment: @Stefan, I would like to know why `mvn compile` tries to download xmltask from Maven Central although the artifact is already downloaded to local repository

Comment: You have checked (in the file system) that the artifact lies within the local repository?

Comment: @JFMeier yes I checked

Comment: The directory in the local repository does _not_ have files that end with lastUpdated?

Comment: @JFMeier, I updated my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory of xmltask and delete all lastupdated files and try again. If this does not help, delete the metadata files as well.

These files signal Maven that the artifact is not available.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I solved my issue by removing file `_remote.repositories`. *lastupdated and *.sha1 were not a problem.